# Retaining the values of an array saved using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4, nsuserdefaults

I have two view controllers. The first one has a segue to another view controller. What I want for the latter view controller is to add items coming from a text field then save it in an array through a button click. Then this array will be saved using NSUserDefaults.

On the code below, I can store items in my array successfully. This array is also saved using NSUserDefaults. Yet, when I get back to my first view controller, and then proceed again to my 2nd view controller to add new items on my array, the items I stored earlier were gone. The newly added items were the only ones saved.

Someone said I have to do some serialization, how is that done? and if there is any other way, advice please :)

in my .h file

```
@interface AddCardViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cardNameTextField;

@end
```

in my .m file

```
@interface AddCardViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *nameOfCards;

@end


@implementation AddCardViewController 

@synthesize cardNameTextField = _cardNameTextField;

@synthesize nameOfCards = _nameOfCards;


// setting my array
- (NSMutableArray *)nameOfCards 
{
    if (!_nameOfCards) _nameOfCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _nameOfCards;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.cardNameTextField.delegate = self;
}


- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.cardNameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //getting the data saved

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *cardName = [defaults objectForKey:@"cardName"];

    NSLog(@"contents of my array %@", cardName);

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)addNewCard:(id)sender {
    [self.nameOfCards addObject:self.cardNameTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"contents :%@", _nameOfCards);


    // this is how to save the data

    NSMutableArray *cardName = _nameOfCards;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:cardName forKey:@"cardName"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"data saved");

}

@end
```

Comment: when you click addnewcard button it saves array in nsuserdefaults . but when you getback to that viewcontroller your array will be nil. so if u add something then it will stored into your array and then it will save in userdefaults. so everytime you added new things in array and userdefaults.

Comment: in addNewCard method - read data from NSUserDefaults into nameOfCards, then add new one, then save

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retain the values of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069593/how-to-retain-the-values-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

so take **mutablearray** in **appdelegate** and **alloc init** in **appdidfinishlaunching**. so if u add something from otherviews it wont replace your data .

Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a hypothetical error is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray * = cardName _nameOfCards;
```

Here _nameOfCards is initialized and then set to 0 elements, then you make a reference with cardName that initially had the value of what storato disk, so now cardName no longer has the old content, but only the new one. From here you're wrong.

You should make a addObject of cardName of _nameOfCards.

Hope that help